# Git ignore all but one file in a folder?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm writing a an app that generates it's own json. I want it to ship with an example json file but to ignore all new files added by developers who use it.

To be specific I have folder `json` which I want to ignore with a single file `json/0.json` which I want committed.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add in gitignore

```
json/
```

for ignoring the folder, and then forcing to add the file

```
git add --force json/0.json
```